# Windows driver installation fails without explanation - where do I view the logs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I'm attempting to install a kernel driver that I have built using Visual Studio Code in Windows 10. Driver signature enforcement is disabled. I've tried two methods to install it:

- Right click the `.inf` > Install - which gives me the following pop up

[image: Errors for Method 1]

- Use `DevCon.exe` as following:

[image: devcon.exe failure]

Both methods fail with no visible explanation. Are there any logs I can look at for either method to see at what point the installation is failing?

Comment: Have you looked in the event viewer?

Comment: @spikey_richie I've looked at the Windows Logs sections and that doesn't contain anything helpful. Is there something in another section? e.g. under the "Application and Services Logs"?

Comment: Probably `Windows > System` or `Windows > Setup`

Comment: @spikey_richie no dice. I've also ran DbgView with kernel capture and there doesn't seem to be any logging related to the installation. So perhaps it's failing in user space? Do you know if the installer wizard launched via Right Click > Install logs anywhere?

Comment: Have a look at SysInternals ProcMon, filtered on Files. Whenever a file is being written to, it gets logged out in ProcMon. That should help you find which file it's writing to.